# How does one store an image, or html code, in a variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor

I am working on a ASP.NET Blazor and C# project. In this project, I have several long form sections. My plan is to have an image change when all of the inputs in a form section are completed. The image will probably just be a green checkmark to show that the user has completed he form section. Here is my code:

```
        void ValidFormSubmitted(EditContext editContext)
        {
            <img src="images/approval-16.ico" alt="Image">
        }
        void InvalidFormSubmitted(EditContext editContext)
        {
            <img src="images/approval-16-grey.ico" alt="Image">
        }
            }
```

When I run it just like this, I get error cs0103 "the name '_builder' does not exist in the current context" in reference to this:

```
#nullable disable
        __builder.AddMarkupContent(0, "            <img src=\"images/approval-16.ico\" alt=\"Image\">\r\n");
#nullable restore
#line 521 "C:\Users\Bryceman\Documents\GitHub\SLC.git\SLC_Road\SLC_Road_Dumping_Web_App\Pages\Statistics\StatisticsEntry.razor"
        }
        void InvalidFormSubmitted(EditContext editContext)
        {

#line default
#line hidden
#nullable disable
        __builder.AddMarkupContent(1, "            <img src=\"images/approval-16-grey.ico\" alt=\"Image\">\r\n");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways this can be achieved, one quick way is that you can have some flags in the form of properties in the page as following:

```
public bool IsStepOneSuccess { get; set; }
public bool IsStepTwoSuccess { get; set; }
public bool IsStepThreeSuccess { get; set; }
```

And you can raise these flags as true when your steps are passed.

```
... // some code to validate step 1

IsStepOneSuccess = true;

... // some other code
```

And in your razor page you will have the following:

```
@if (IsStepOneSuccess)
{
    <img src="images/approval-16.ico" alt="Image">
}
else 
{
    <img src="images/approval-16-grey.ico" alt="Image">
}
```

Comment: One more question, how can I locate the image to a spot in the page that I want without moving the logic chain as well?

Comment: You will have to add the logic in the place where you want the image to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a bug in the asp.net core framework.
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/13275

Comment: Apparently so, but is there anything I can do now to get working this project?